# Populate picklist values in a VF page programatically from an Object's field

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a custom object 'Object_1__c' and a field of this named as Decription__c.  I want to display all the descriptions from this object to another visual force page programatically using apex.
Could anyone help me out with any useful links?

Answer (score 2):

All of this should be possible by generating a [`List`](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_list.htm) of [`SelectOption`](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/apex_pages_selectoption.htm) as part of your [`Controller`](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_controller_custom.htm). You can then throw that `List` of `SelectOption` on the page using [`<apex:selectList>`](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm) and [`<apex:selectOptions>`](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectOptions.htm). Here is an example:

```
public with sharing class Controller {
    public List<SelectOption> objectOptions {get;set;}
    public Id selectedObject{get;set;}
    public Controller() {
        objectOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Object_1__c> objects = [SELECT Id, Description__c FROM Object_1__c];
        for(Object_1__c object:objects){
            objectOptions.add(new SelectOption(object.Id, object.Description__c));
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:selectList value="{!selectedObject}">
    <apex:selectOptions value="{!objectOptions}"/>
</apex:selectList>
```

Comment: if you replace the variable name `object` with something like `obj` you can even prevent the compiler from issuing a warning... ;-)